# How does intron retention make the alternative transcript non-coding?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, molecular-biology, molecular-genetics

I faced with a non-coding transcript that specified as one the isoform of [BIN1](http://www.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Transcript/Summary?db=core;g=ENSG00000136717;r=2:127048033-127056491;t=ENST00000462958).

It sounds that this isoform generated as a result of alternative splicing with a intron retained; am I right? However, Ensembl reports that the transcript has 5 exons, could you please let me know more about this event? How does the transcript have 5 exons and all are non-coding?
Also, I'll glad to hear why the organism or cell has retained such a transcripts? they have any function?
Thanks

Comment: An exon is just a sequence that is retained in the mature RNA. It doesn't have to be protein coding.

Comment: I could not find the sequence of this transcript but it must have become non coding most probably because retention of the intron must have caused a frameshift leading to loss of the ORF (there are no stop codons).

Comment: Some changes could also destabilize RNA and make the turnover so fast that it does not code. As an example, the intron could add a target for interfering RNA (siRNA) that both blocks translation and forces the degradation.